# How to give priority to image icon in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Good morning, is there any way to prioritize an image icon within the open layer? Since I would like to bring some icons that I have left under others and wanting to move them I have to zoom in a lot so that they are isolated from the rest.

The problem is that these icons are of origin and destination of NOMINATIM use addresses and based on those a line with bus stops is drawn.

The code is the following:

```
image: new i({
 //scale: .7,
 anchor: [0.5, 46],
 anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
 anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
 opacity: 0.95,
 src: g
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the zIndex of the parent style:

```
new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    ...
    ...
  }),
  zIndex: ... 
})
```

or to change a feature where a style is already set

```
feature.getStyle().setZIndex(...);
```

Comment: How would the implementation be?
     zIndex: 1, (for which I want it to be below) and,
     zIndex: 2, (for which I want it to be above the previous one)

Comment: Yes, higher values will position the feature above lower values.